# protobuf and pkg-Config missing libdir and includedirs

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, pkg-config

I was trying to build a binary for the protocol buffers C++ AddressBook tutorial. I compiled the protocol buffers successfully, but when I was building the binary with g++, I used pkg-config to get cflags and libs, and it failed to locate the necessary headers. I manually passed all the necessary flags, include directories, library directories, etc. to g++ and it worked.

- **pkg-config --cflags protobuf** returns "-pthread"
- **pkg-config --libs protobuf** returns "-lprotobuf -pthread -lpthread"

Meanwhile, protobuf.pc lists:

- **Cflags**: -I${includedir} -pthread
- **Libs:** -L${libdir} -lprotobuf -pthread -lpthread

I confirmed that the variables are set correctly with --variable=(include/libdir), and when using the --debug option, it confirms variables are set. However, it also shows that the -I and -L options are removed. The following is truncated debug output.

```
...Pasing pacage file protobuf.pc...
...Variable declarations...
Unknown keyword 'Libs.private' in protobuf.pc
...More variable declarations...
Adding 'protobuf' to list of known packages
Package protobuf has -I/usr/include in Cflags
Removing -I/usr/include from cflags for protobuf
Package protobuf has -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu in Libs
Removing -L /usr/libx86-64-linux-gnu from libs for protobuf
```